# Django hosting on pythonanywhere.com/

Tags: django, pythonanywhere

How can I upload my finished django local project to pythonanywhere.com? Is there any option or I should to do file by file?

I have right now something like this [My Django website on pythonanywhere](http://krajeto.pythonanywhere.com)
but I don't see there how to upload my finished project :(

I uploaded a zip file but how to unzip it by bash console?

Answer (score 4):

To unzip the file from a bash console, just start one from the "Consoles" tab and then run `unzip filename.zip`.

Answer (score 0):

from [here](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/details/django_hosting):

> Getting code and content in and out is easy — you can use our built-in
>   browser-based editor and Bash consoles, scp, or you can use git,
>   mercurial and other VCS's to push and pull your code. You can even
>   sync up via Dropbox.

**update**

The Dropbox feature is not available anymore, and see first comment below

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here: the reference to Dropbox is actually incorrect, we had to remove that feature a while back.  I'll get the text on the site fixed.  The other features should all work fine though.

Comment: @GilesThomas thank you. I've updated the answer to highlight that issue, I'll fix the quote when you update the text on your site